# i need filter array length javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
[
[
    {
        "support": 7,
        "items": [
            9
        ]
    },
    {
        "support": 7,
        "items": [
            8
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "support": 7,
        "items": [
            9
        ]
    },
    {
        "support": 5,
        "items": [
            10
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "support": 7,
        "items": [
            9
        ]
    },
    {
        "items": [
            2,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    }
],
[
    {
        "support": 7,
        "items": [
            9
        ]
    },
    {
        "items": [
            7,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    }
],
[
    {
        "support": 7,
        "items": [
            9
        ]
    },
    {
        "items": [
            8,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    }
],
[
    {
        "support": 5,
        "items": [
            10
        ]
    },
    {
        "support": 5,
        "items": [
            1
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "support": 5,
        "items": [
            10
        ]
    },
    {
        "support": 6,
        "items": [
            2
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "support": 5,
        "items": [
            10
        ]
    },
    {
        "support": 5,
        "items": [
            4
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "support": 5,
        "items": [
            10
        ]
    },
    {
        "support": 6,
        "items": [
            7
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "support": 5,
        "items": [
            10
        ]
    },
    {
        "support": 7,
        "items": [
            8
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "support": 5,
        "items": [
            10
        ]
    },
    {
        "support": 7,
        "items": [
            9
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "support": 5,
        "items": [
            10
        ]
    },
    {
        "items": [
            2,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    }
],
[
    {
        "support": 5,
        "items": [
            10
        ]
    },
    {
        "items": [
            7,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    }
],
[
    {
        "support": 5,
        "items": [
            10
        ]
    },
    {
        "items": [
            8,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    }
],
[
    {
        "items": [
            2,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    },
    {
        "support": 5,
        "items": [
            1
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "items": [
            2,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    },
    {
        "support": 6,
        "items": [
            2
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "items": [
            2,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    },
    {
        "support": 5,
        "items": [
            4
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "items": [
            2,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    },
    {
        "support": 6,
        "items": [
            7
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "items": [
            2,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    },
    {
        "support": 7,
        "items": [
            8
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "items": [
            2,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    },
    {
        "support": 7,
        "items": [
            9
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "items": [
            2,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    },
    {
        "support": 5,
        "items": [
            10
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "items": [
            2,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    },
    {
        "items": [
            7,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    }
],
[
    {
        "items": [
            2,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    },
    {
        "items": [
            8,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    }
],
[
    {
        "items": [
            7,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    },
    {
        "support": 5,
        "items": [
            1
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "items": [
            7,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    },
    {
        "support": 6,
        "items": [
            2
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "items": [
            7,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    },
    {
        "support": 5,
        "items": [
            4
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "items": [
            7,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    },
    {
        "support": 6,
        "items": [
            7
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "items": [
            7,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    },
    {
        "support": 7,
        "items": [
            8
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "items": [
            7,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    },
    {
        "support": 7,
        "items": [
            9
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "items": [
            7,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    },
    {
        "support": 5,
        "items": [
            10
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "items": [
            7,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    },
    {
        "items": [
            2,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    }
],
[
    {
        "items": [
            7,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    },
    {
        "items": [
            8,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    }
],
[
    {
        "items": [
            8,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    },
    {
        "support": 5,
        "items": [
            1
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "items": [
            8,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    },
    {
        "support": 6,
        "items": [
            2
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "items": [
            8,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    },
    {
        "support": 5,
        "items": [
            4
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "items": [
            8,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    },
    {
        "support": 6,
        "items": [
            7
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "items": [
            8,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    },
    {
        "support": 7,
        "items": [
            8
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "items": [
            8,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    },
    {
        "support": 7,
        "items": [
            9
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "items": [
            8,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    },
    {
        "support": 5,
        "items": [
            10
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "items": [
            8,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    },
    {
        "items": [
            2,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    }
],
[
    {
        "items": [
            8,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    },
    {
        "items": [
            7,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    }
]
```

]

```
result7 = newcom.filter(function (a) {
                        return a.some(function (b) {
                            return b.support && b.items.length == 2 || b.items.length == 1 && b.support;
                        });
                    });
```

> Above my json, I've tried to filter the items for such a result but failed. Whether anyone has a solution for the result like the array below, to get the [x, Y] Item and the item [x], please help me. Above is the result of my thought code that always fail to show the results I want
> Above my json, I've tried to filter the items for such a result but failed. Whether anyone has a solution for the result like the array below, to get the [x, Y] Item and the item [x], please help me. Above is the result of my thought code that always fail to show the results I want

```
[
[
    {
        "items": [
            2,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    },
    {
        "support": 6,
        "items": [
            2
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "items": [
            7,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    },
    {
        "support": 6,
        "items": [
            7
        ]
    }
],
[
    {
        "items": [
            8,
            9
        ],
        "support": 5
    },
    {
        "support": 7,
        "items": [
            8
        ]
    }
]
```

]

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` with combine conditions.

```js
const filter = (arr) =>
  arr.filter(
    ([xy1, xy2]) =>
      xy1.items.length === 2 &&
      xy2.items.length === 1 &&
      xy1.items[0] === xy2.items[0]
  );

const items = [
  [
    {
      support: 7,
      items: [9],
    },
    {
      support: 7,
      items: [8],
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      support: 7,
      items: [9],
    },
    {
      support: 5,
      items: [10],
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      support: 7,
      items: [9],
    },
    {
      items: [2, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      support: 7,
      items: [9],
    },
    {
      items: [7, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      support: 7,
      items: [9],
    },
    {
      items: [8, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      support: 5,
      items: [10],
    },
    {
      support: 5,
      items: [1],
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      support: 5,
      items: [10],
    },
    {
      support: 6,
      items: [2],
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      support: 5,
      items: [10],
    },
    {
      support: 5,
      items: [4],
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      support: 5,
      items: [10],
    },
    {
      support: 6,
      items: [7],
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      support: 5,
      items: [10],
    },
    {
      support: 7,
      items: [8],
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      support: 5,
      items: [10],
    },
    {
      support: 7,
      items: [9],
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      support: 5,
      items: [10],
    },
    {
      items: [2, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      support: 5,
      items: [10],
    },
    {
      items: [7, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      support: 5,
      items: [10],
    },
    {
      items: [8, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      items: [2, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
    {
      support: 5,
      items: [1],
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      items: [2, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
    {
      support: 6,
      items: [2],
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      items: [2, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
    {
      support: 5,
      items: [4],
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      items: [2, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
    {
      support: 6,
      items: [7],
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      items: [2, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
    {
      support: 7,
      items: [8],
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      items: [2, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
    {
      support: 7,
      items: [9],
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      items: [2, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
    {
      support: 5,
      items: [10],
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      items: [2, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
    {
      items: [7, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      items: [2, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
    {
      items: [8, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      items: [7, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
    {
      support: 5,
      items: [1],
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      items: [7, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
    {
      support: 6,
      items: [2],
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      items: [7, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
    {
      support: 5,
      items: [4],
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      items: [7, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
    {
      support: 6,
      items: [7],
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      items: [7, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
    {
      support: 7,
      items: [8],
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      items: [7, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
    {
      support: 7,
      items: [9],
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      items: [7, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
    {
      support: 5,
      items: [10],
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      items: [7, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
    {
      items: [2, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      items: [7, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
    {
      items: [8, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      items: [8, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
    {
      support: 5,
      items: [1],
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      items: [8, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
    {
      support: 6,
      items: [2],
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      items: [8, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
    {
      support: 5,
      items: [4],
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      items: [8, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
    {
      support: 6,
      items: [7],
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      items: [8, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
    {
      support: 7,
      items: [8],
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      items: [8, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
    {
      support: 7,
      items: [9],
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      items: [8, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
    {
      support: 5,
      items: [10],
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      items: [8, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
    {
      items: [2, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
  ],
  [
    {
      items: [8, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
    {
      items: [7, 9],
      support: 5,
    },
  ],
];

console.log(filter(items));
```